How to get depth data from the PX4 Gazebo simulation and visualize it in RVIZ2?
I started the simulation using make px4_sitl gz_x500_depth and able to control the simulated drone using QGroundControl as well.
I used the ros_gz_bridge to publish camera and point cloud data.
ros2 run ros_gz_bridge parameter_bridge /camera@sensor_msgs/msg/Image@ignition.msgs.Image /camera_info@sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo@ignition.msgs.CameraInfo /depth_camera/points@sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2@gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked /depth_camera@sensor_msgs/msg/Image@ignition.msgs.Image

I added objects in front of the camera and able to visualize the images in RVIZ2.
I added the PointCloud2 topic into RVIZ2 display but there is no depth point cloud displayed. I am seeing a warning message that says
Fixed Frame
No tf data. Actual error: Frame [base_link] does not exist

in the Global Status widget.
Any help is much appreciated.
